# Wildcard formatting in XML & XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, wildcard, typography

Why doesn't this line:

**`apply-templates select="*/*`** (under the "shop" element in the XSLT file)

apply bold formatting to `Blake2`? The output looks like this:

> Start of root in XSLT
>
> "Step 1 start" **Alexis** (Task: Sales )
>   **Employee2** (Task: ) Blake2 "Step 1 done"
>
> End of root in XSLT

My question is, why isn't `Blake2` also in bold? It's under the `<employee>` element.

Changing that line to **`*apply-templates select="*"`** causes `Blake2` to be in bold. What makes this different?

Here's the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="2.xsl" ?>

<root>
    <shop>
        <person> 
            <employee> 
                <name> Alexis </name> 
                <role> Manager </role> 
                <task> Sales </task> 
            </employee> 

            <employee>
                <name> Employee2 </name>
            </employee>
        </person>

        <employee>
            <name> Blake2 </name>
        </employee>

    </shop>

</root>
```

Here's the XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="root"> 
<html><head></head> 
<body>
Start of root in XSLT <p/> <xsl:apply-templates /> <p/>

End of root in XSLT

</body> 
</html> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="shop">
"Step 1 start"
<xsl:apply-templates select="*/*"/>
"Step 1 done" <p/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="employee"> 
<b> <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/> </b> 
(Task: <xsl:apply-templates select="task"/>) 
<br></br> 
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your third template does not select any `<employee>` elements in your document. It just selects `<employee>` elements that are direct child nodes of the current element. On the root level, this does not apply to any elements, but as the second template is invoked by the `<apply-templates>` in the first element, and the second template applies templates with the (relative!) path `*/*` (i.e. templates for any elements that are children of the children of the current element), the `<employee>` element in the `<person>` element gets selected.

The second `<employee>` element is not a child of a child of the `<shop>` element, but a direct child of the `<shop>` element, and hence doesn't get selected by `*/*` starting at `<shop>`.

When you change `*/*` to `*`, both `<employee>` elements get selected: The second one gets selected because it directly matches `*` (a direct child of `<shop>`). `*` also selects `<person>`, and as there is no template specified for that element, the default behavior will be executed, meaning that templates will be applied to the children of `<person>`, which includes the first `<employee>` element.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I understand what you said, but I thought that "xsl:template match" will be able to find any element in the XML file, that matches the keyword (which is "employee" in this case)?

Also, I thought that the way XML & XSLT works is that whenever an element in the XML is about to be executed, it will first look through the XSLT file for any corresponding template. If it finds a matching template for that particular element, then it will execute it (just like the shop template in my question).

Comment: The `template` just matches elements that match the XPath expression as seen from the current node. The current node is any node that the template is tested on - by default, the root element, as well as any child nodes of nodes that are not matched by any template, as well as any nodes that are explicitly selected with `<apply-templates>` statements. None of this applies to the second `<employee>` element; it is not subject to the default behavior of applying templates to child nodes, as there is a template applied to its parent node (`<shop>`), so the default behavior is overridden.

Comment: (Continued).....So when the apply-templates select="*/*" was executed, it finds shop/person/employee and shop/employee/name. Just looking at shop/employee/name, I know we get the name "Blake2", but what I don't understand is when it found the "employee" element, wouldn't it then look for the matching template in the XSLT file, as it would find there is indeed an employee template, and would format "Blake2" by making it bold? But instead, it skipped that and jumped straight to the "name" (child node) of "employee", and simply output "Blake2" without making it bold...

Comment: It never finds shop/employee. You got it right by saying that it only finds shop/person/employee and shop/employee/name. So, the only `<employee>` elements that it finds are the two shop/person/employee ones, and they are what the template is applied to. Intermediate elements that are mentioned in the XPath are not considered, only the resulting nodes from the XPath expression are.

Comment: This is rather more simple: Just having defined a template doesn't guarantee that this template will be selected for execution. Templates are selected for execution if there is an `xsl:apply-templates` issued that selects a node that is matched by that template and there are no other templates with higher import precedence or priority. This includes a template being selected for execution by an `xsl:apply-templates` that resides in one of the XSLT *built-in* templates that are executed whenever there is no other matching template found.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: you are misleading people by saying *The template just matches elements that match the XPath expression as seen from the current node*. Code like `<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/shop/person/employee" />` will cause a template with `match="employee"` to be instantiated regardless of the current node.

Comment: @Borodin: Code like `<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/shop/person/employee" />` will cause the `<employee>` element(s) selected by the XPath expression to *become* the current node(s) at some point.

Comment: @Borodin: Sorry, understood only now what you were getting at: Right, when an XPath expression is tested based on the current node, and that XPath expression happens to be absolute, it will always return the same result set no matter what the current node is. That lies in the nature of absolute paths, so I didn't want to further complicate the explanations, but you're right that with an absolute XPath, that template will always be applied.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: absolute or relative it makes no difference. In the question a template with `select="*/*"` is applied when the current element is `<shop>`. That selects the first two `<employee>` elements (and invokes the corresponding template) and the 3rd `<name>` element (which is processed by the default template). At no time are the parent elements - `<person>` and `<employee>` - the current node. A `match="XPath"` is invoked when the XPath can match the current node from any point in the tree, so for instance `match="*/*"` matches when the current node is any element with a parent element

Comment: @Borodin: Correct, like I wrote above - *Intermediate elements that are mentioned in the XPath are not considered, only the resulting nodes from the XPath expression are.*

Comment: I believe you are imagining this wrongly, but I don't think it's useful to pursue it here. There is no sense in which a template match is relative to the current node. Dimitre explains it in a different way above.

Answer (score 0):

**First, lets see how an xslt processor works.** In order for the templates in an xslt to be ran/instantiated/activated, they must "match". Now, ask yourself this:

- what do they match on?
- What, for instance, is the *thing* that satisfies `match="root"`?

As the xslt is loaded, the input document, or rather it's top level node, is brought under its attention. Your input document starts with a `root` node, so that's what goes into the xslt first. It immediately satisfies `match="root"`. Simple.

**Now for the `employee`**, when will that little gem be matched?

Well, the xslt processor is not going to loop through every possible node and see if it has a template that matches. *It only does that for the nodes you tell it to*.

- This is what you do with `xsl:apply-templates select='...'`.
- In order for the `employee`-nodes in the input to be xslt-ed, they need to be selected in a `xsl:apply-templates` somewhere.

**Ok, so what happened?** In your `shop` template, you select `*/*` to apply templates to, meaning 'the children of the current node's children' ('grandchildren', if you like).

- The current node in the `shop` template being `shop` means that the two employee nodes inside the person node get selected (`*/*` expands to `person/employee`).
- Blake2 is a sibling of the `shop` node, and does not get selected.
- Changing to `*` for the `select` returns the `person` and `employee` nodes that are children of the shop node.

**So where does the *non-bold Blake2* come from?** Well, the non-bold Blake2 does not stem from any template you created, he is merely victim of default behavior, where text nodes but not element nodes get copied over from the input to the output.

---

You have some stuff to learn if you want to really use xslt. I suggest starting with an identity-transform (Google's your friend), then delete some elements by providing an empty template for them. Than do a one-to-one translation, say, capitalize all elements. Mix in attributes. Try to make more strict matches using xpath conditions (`[this stuff]`). Have a look at more complex structures such as conditionals and looping constructs. Dive into variables, parameters and call-template. Use document().

Have fun!